# How to document makefile templates and include *.mk file interfaces?

Tags: documentation, makefile, doxygen

We have a number of makefile templates, that realize certain build actions by setting a few parameter makefile variables, and applying a makefile template via inclusion like

```
GENERIC_PARAM1-y := paramA
GENERIC_PARAM2-y := paramB

include $(MAKE_TOOLS)/doaction.mk
```

And files like `doaction.mk` contain make templates to generate standard rule definitions that are applied when just including the action make step.

Now we want to document these interfaces for the `*.mk` snippets using Doxygen like

```
## @file
## @brief doaction.mk is purposed to ...
## 
## Some more detailed descriptions about rules applied ...
## @param GENERIC_PARAM1-y Parameter1 description ...
## @param GENERIC_PARAM2-y Parameter2 description ...
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this using any valid Doxygen syntax/configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"Is there a simple way to achieve this using any valid doxygen syntax/configuration?"*

Yes, you can use doxygen's `INPUT_FILTER`, `FILE_PATTERNS` and `FILTER_SOURCE_FILES` configuration settings [as stolen from this blog post](http://rickfoosusa.blogspot.de/2011/08/howto-have-doxygen-support-bash-script.html)

**Put these settings in your `Doxyfile` configuration**

```
FILE_PATTERNS = *.mk 
INPUT_FILTER = "sed -e 's|##|//!|'" 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES = YES
```

The `INPUT_FILTER` actually does the trick, the `sed` command is used by doxygen to open a pipe filtering the input files along the specified command.

**Note:**
The above mentioned command isn't embedded into a shell, thus chained command statements like

```
"grep '##' | sed -e 's|##|//!|'"
```

won't work.

---

Put your comments as proposed in the sample `##` will expand for comments seen by doxygen

```
## @file
## @brief doaction.mk is purposed to ...
## 
## Some more detailed descriptions about rules applied ...
## @param GENERIC_PARAM1-y Parameter1 description ...
## @param GENERIC_PARAM2-y Parameter2 description ...
```

Additionally you should put a

```
## @cond
...
## @endcond
```

around your makefile rules/templates code, to avoid doxygen parsing these parts.

The above sample should render as follows in the generated documentation HTML

[image]

Comment: For those who want to do this on a windows OS and have no 'sed' available:
You can use the powershell command 'get-content' to do the replacing. As doxygen will apply the filter in the form '<filter> <input-file>' but 'get-content' will want to have it 'get-content <input-file> <filter>' here is a little workaround. Place this command in a *.cmd in the same directory as your doxyfile is and put this line in it:
@powershell -Command "get-content %1 | %%{$_ -replace \"##\",\"//!\"}"

Your filter rule should look like this then:
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.mk="lud.cmd"